# How getPocket retrieve content?

Tags: javascript

How can I develop the feature for webapp to automatically retrieve articles by link? What is the name of that function?
I have no idea how difficult is it.
May be there are some kind of libraries to do that?

Comment: Have you googled it?

Comment: I didn't find any suitable answers

Comment: What articles are you trying to get? Please fill out the question with some more details